# BrainTree JavaScript Drop In API and Kount Device Data not being set

Tags: javascript, braintree, braintree-javascript

I'm trying to add Kount Fraud protection to an existing BrainTree Drop In installation and according to the docs I should just be able to provide a data collector to start the flow:

```
braintree.dropin.create({
        authorization: clientToken,
        container: '#dropin-container',
        // add the data collector for Kount
        dataCollector: {
            kount: true
        },
        card: {
            amount: amount,
            currency: "USD"
        }      
    },
    function(createErr, instance) {
        button.on("click", function() {
            instance.requestPaymentMethod(function (err, payload) {
                   // payload.deviceData is 'undefined'
               });
            });
    });
```

The problem is that `payload.deviceData is always undefined.

The docs are not really clear what dependencies are required for the **drop in** component. It shows the scripts for the client component but not the drop in.

I'm using:

```
<!--  <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.57.0/js/client.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/dropin/1.22.0/js/dropin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.57.0/js/data-collector.min.js"></script>
```

Is 1.22 the correct version to be using for the drop in? Is that the last version? I can't find an official way to check which versions should be used other than what's in the drop in docs which use 1.22?

Also tried adding the `client.min.js` in (in addition to drop because without dropin the code above won't find the `braintree.dropin.create`.

Any idea what's missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure, I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, I recommend contacting [Support](https://help.braintreepayments.com).</sub>

You're definitely on the latest version (as of the post). I like to check the [`CHANGELOG.md`](https://github.com/braintree/braintree-web-drop-in/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1220) when needing to double-check the version.

In order for device data to be collected, you need to have [Advanced Fraud Tools](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/guides/fraud-tools/advanced/overview) enabled in your gateway. I'd start with checking this, as device data will be undefined when this is turned off. To enable Advanced Fraud Tools, follow these steps:

1. Log into the [Control Panel](https://www.braintreegateway.com/login) (or [sandbox Control Panel](https://sandbox.braintreegateway.com/login)
2. Click on the gear icon in the top right corner
3. Click Fraud Management from the drop-down menu
4. Next to Advanced Fraud Tools, click the toggle to turn it on

Additionally, the data collector should be [included in the Drop-in UI script](https://github.com/braintree/braintree-web-drop-in/blob/4e2b3bf127582a2aa4c9c66bce9214e64936b036/src/lib/data-collector.js#L24-L27) and you should not need to include the data collector script tag. The Drop-in should be ready to go without that.

Comment: Ah - yes that's it! I turned it on in production, but totally forgot to do it in the sandbox. Once I turned it on in the SandBox the device data is coming in.